# how to find the sum of multiple numbers from a column in a sql database in python?

Tags: python, sql, sum, multiple-columns

I have a database that has a bookings table in. One of the columns in the bookings table is 'incomes', and another one is 'date_of_booking,' which stores dates in 'DD/MM/YYYY' format. I am trying to write a feature that lets a user input a month, and from that will calculate all the incomes from that month. So far I have this:

```
    validMonth = False
    while not validMonth:
    lookForMonth = input('What month, please? (number from 1 through 12):')
    try:
        validMonth = 1<=int(lookForMonth)<=12
    except:
        pass

    sqlCmd = 'SELECT date FROM bookings WHERE SUBSTR(date,4,2)="%.2i"' %    int(lookForMonth)
    for row in conn.execute(sqlCmd):
    print (row)
```

With this code, I am able to output the date of bookings for a particular month. However I want to output the total incomes for a particular month. What do I need to add so that this works out the total incomes for a particular month and outputs it? Any help would be gladly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace one statement.

```
SELECT sum(income) FROM bookings where SUBSTR(date,4,2)='04'
```

As in:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('CREATE TABLE bookings (date text, income real)')
c.execute('''INSERT INTO bookings VALUES ('01/04/2017', 19.22)''')
c.execute('''INSERT INTO bookings VALUES ('15/04/2017', 19.22)''')
c.execute('''INSERT INTO bookings VALUES ('22/04/2017', 19.22)''')

validMonth = False
while not validMonth:
    lookForMonth = input('What month, please? (number from 1 through 12):')
    try:
        validMonth = 1<=int(lookForMonth)<=12
    except:
        pass


sql = '''SELECT sum(income) FROM bookings where SUBSTR(date,4,2)="%.2i"''' % int(lookForMonth)
for row in c.execute(sql):
    print (row)
```

Resulting output:

```
What month, please? (number from 1 through 12):4
(57.66,)
```

Comment: one question though, how could i change the 'sql = '''SELECT sum(income) FROM bookings where SUBSTR(date,4,2)="04"''' ' line so that it lets the user input a month, as supposed to searching for the month '04'?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you want to select both in your sql statement.

```
sqlCmd = 'SELECT date_of_booking,incomes FROM bookings WHERE SUBSTR(date,4,2)="%.2i"' %    int(lookForMonth)
income_sum = 0
for (row_date, row_income) in conn.execute(sqlCmd):
    income_sum += row_income
    print row_date

print income_sum
```

Then you can specify both date and income of the row in your loop like above.